# How to get code that is a ruby Gem?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, github

I am pretty new to GitHub, and I want to use some Ruby code soted up there and try it out.

This is the code I want to get: https://github.com/pengwynn/linkedin

And I would like to get it as a Ruby Gem so I can use it to connect to the LinkedIn API.

How would I go about it? I tried clicking around on the page there, but I am just not sure what is the correct-practice way of doing things there.

I forked the master branch and now I have a copy in my account, but not sure if that was the correct action.

Thanks for your suggestions. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to fetch newest version of gem directly from git repository, you can just:

```
gem install git://github.com/pengwynn/linkedin.git
```

---

Also you can build gem from source code using the rake task called "gem"

```
git clone git://github.com/pengwynn/linkedin.git
cd linkedin
rake gem
```

And then install it

```
gem install pkg/linkedin-{version}.gem
```

Comment: @Flexiod thanks - just so I understand, can I make any Ruby code I find on GitHub into a Gem by doing that command, or just the code that the author somehow made into a gem?

Comment: You can use as gem only specially prepared for that packages.

Comment: thanks - how do I tell that a package is specifically prepared as a gem? And how do people tell what the gem name is? Some people answering the question knew the name of the gem is specifically likedin

Comment: and when I run bundle update, where does it know to pull the specified gems from? Thanks!! :) Sorry too many questions :)

Comment: You can read about making gem, for example, [here](http://guides.rubygems.org/make-your-own-gem/). There are answers of all your questions =)

Comment: And bundler knows where to pull gems from rubygems repository.

Answer (score 2):

If you want it as a gem, and have ruby installed already, you can use the gem command to install it.

The command is on the documentation page that you linked above:

```
gem install linkedin
```

Comment: thanks! Just so I am clear, what is the difference in doing that command as opposed to the command suggested by Flexoid? Thanks!! :)

Comment: The difference is that Donovan's solution looks at a list of possible repositories (probably starting out with RubyGems.org and possibly getting referred to github) rather than just looking directly at github.  If you don't know where the latest version of the gem is stored, Donovan's method is the most reliable.

Comment: @Flexoid's command actually doesn't work for me (perhaps I'm missing a plugin or haven't sourced github or something) as gem thinks its trying to find a gem called 'git://github.com/pengwynn/linkedin.git'

It would appear that Flexoid's command is attempting to pull the gem directly from the github website whereas the normal 'gem install [gemname]' looks in the repositories you have listed under 'gem sources' for valid gems of that name and installs them.

Answer (score 1):

You should be using `git` to pull down a copy. If you're not familiar with the command-line tool, you might want a shell that walks you through the process. It is not necessary to fork a personal copy unless you want to make modifications to it.

Installing gems is done through the `gem` tool, as in `gem install linkedin`, though using [bundler](http://gembundler.com/) is recommended as it makes keeping the versions in sync on different machines much easier.

If it's a Ruby gem you can always install it and then inspect the contents with `gem contents linkedin` or whatever the gem name is.

Comment: thanks! In general, how do I tell if some ruby code on GitHub is a rubygem or not?

Comment: Ah I see, so should I add the reference of the LinkedIn gem to my gemfile, and then do bundle update? Thank you! :)